# Regex conditional match

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

```
• ~!@ to act as a placeholder in positions 1-3
•   Asterisks are permitted in positions 2-5.
•   Position One should be alphabetic (except for the ~!@)
•   No characters should accept numbers.
•   Other than the exceptions mentioned above, no special characters are allowed
```

Means if my 1st word ia alphabet then 2-5 can be Alpha or *(2-5 is not mandatory but if we enter then it should be either alpha or *)

But if we are using ~ then 2-3 position should be !@.

Right now I am using

```
^[a-zA-Z~][a-zA-Z*]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Comment: You really need to clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: Please add the expected results (one or two string that matches, and one or two that shouldn't match)

Comment: What is the minimal length of the string?

Answer (score 2):

As the original regex works for the case where the string begins with a letter, keep it and add an alternation for strings that begin with `~!@`:

```
^(?i)(?:[a-z][a-z*]{0,4}[a-z]*|~!@[a-z*]{0,2}[a-z]*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

This fit the requirements (case_insensitive):

```
^(?:~!@|[a-z][a-z*]{0,2})[a-z*]{0,2}[a-z]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z*]{0,4}[a-zA-Z]*$|^~[!@]{2}[a-zA-Z*][a-zA-Z]*$
```

You can try this.This should fulfill all your conditions.It uses `|` operator to match string starting from `~` and the other case.